# iOS animating object goes back to original position

Tags: ios, swift, animation, position, core-animation

I am trying to animate the position of a UIView object with CABasicAnimation on a button Tap. The object animated and moves to the 'to' position, but returns back to the original position after the animation ends. I want to retain the position of the view object even after the animation ends. This the code snippet that performs the animation. viewObject is the object which I'm trying to animate.

```
let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "position")
animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(controlPoints: 0.86, 0, 0.07, 1.0)
animation.duration = 0.5
animation.fromValue = NSValue(cgPoint: CGPoint(x: viewObject.center.x, y: viewObject.center.y))
animation.toValue = NSValue(cgPoint: CGPoint(x: viewObject.center.x + 64, y: viewObject.center.y))
viewObject.layer.add(animation, forKey: "position")
```

Comment: animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
 animation.removedOnCompletion = NO;

Comment: please try this

Comment: This fixed the problem. But I'm unclear about why should I set the fillMode property.

Comment: By default, it is set to kCAFillModeRemoved, which means that the animation changes are undone when the animation is completed. If you switch it to kCAFillModeForwards, the changes caused by the animation will hang around.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

add following lines before adding animation

```
animation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
```

**Swift**

```
animation.fillMode = .forwards
animation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
```

Answer (score 7):

Please add the following code:

**Objective-C:**

```
animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
animation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
```

**Swift 4:**

```
animation.fillMode = .forwards
animation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to give frame again on completion. So, this can be a nice approach

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.7, delay: 1.0, options: .curveLinear, animations: {

   let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "position")
    animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(controlPoints: 0.86, 0, 0.07, 1.0)
    animation.duration = 0.5
    animation.fromValue = NSValue(cgPoint: CGPoint(x: self.viewObject.center.x, y: self.viewObject.center.y))
    animation.toValue = NSValue(cgPoint: CGPoint(x: self.viewObject.center.x + 64, y: self.viewObject.center.y))
    self.viewObject.layer.add(animation, forKey: "position")

}, completion: { finished in
    self.viewObject.frame.origin.x = self.viewObject.frame.origin.x + 64

})
```

Try this. It will work perfectly

Answer (score 0):

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.7, delay: 1.0, options: .CurveEaseOut, animations:
{
    Code
}, completion: 
{ 
   finished in
   println("Nothing to do!")
})
```

Just do animation inside a block and when it finishes. hold that position and do not revert back. It should stay at same position

and add this line inside code
`cabasicanimation.removedOnCompletion = false;`
This line will make it do not go back in the same state

Comment: This is old syntax . Atleast check before answering.

Answer (score 0):

If you want keep your position, you should put your code same my structure

```
CATransaction.begin()
CATransaction.setDisableActions(true)
CATransaction.setCompletionBlock {
   // Input code set new position at here
}
// Intput code animation
CATransaction.commit()
```